# Tensorflow C++ API guide examples on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow

I built tensorflow with VS2015 and I was able to run some examples,
as `tf_tutorials_example_trainer` and `label_image`.
Then I tried to run the samples [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/cc/guide).
 I was able to compile and start the `example.cc` but when reaching the line

```
Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
```

I get this error:

```
Op type not registered 'NoOp' in binary running on DESKTOP-S5QHRCE.
Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://joe-antognini.github.io/machine-learning/windows-tf-project).
Thanks to Joe, who explains how to use the `/WHOLEARCHIVE` option to fix the issue.
To avoid out `of memory error` during linking if using `Optimize for debugging (/DEBUG)` option, do `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release youproject.vcxproj` in a command prompt.